# Finding clusters depending on temporal distance with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to identify clusters in a dataframe that are within 4 subsequent days of the first event. Additionally we have a grouping variable.

Here is an example:

```
startDate <- as.POSIXct("2022-10-01")

dt1 <- data.table(
  id = 1:20,
  timestamp = startDate+ lubridate::days(rep(1:10,2))+ lubridate::hours(1:20),
  group_id = rep(c("A","B"), each= 10)
  )
```

```
    id           timestamp group_id        t_diff
 1:  1 2022-10-02 01:00:00        A 0.000000 days
 2:  2 2022-10-03 02:00:00        A 1.041667 days
 3:  3 2022-10-04 03:00:00        A 2.083333 days
 4:  4 2022-10-05 04:00:00        A 3.125000 days
 5:  5 2022-10-06 05:00:00        A 4.166667 days
 6:  6 2022-10-07 06:00:00        A 5.208333 days
 7:  7 2022-10-08 07:00:00        A 6.250000 days
 8:  8 2022-10-09 08:00:00        A 7.291667 days
 9:  9 2022-10-10 09:00:00        A 8.333333 days
10: 10 2022-10-11 10:00:00        A 9.375000 days
11: 11 2022-10-02 11:00:00        B 0.000000 days
12: 12 2022-10-03 12:00:00        B 1.041667 days
13: 13 2022-10-04 13:00:00        B 2.083333 days
14: 14 2022-10-05 14:00:00        B 3.125000 days
15: 15 2022-10-06 15:00:00        B 4.166667 days
16: 16 2022-10-07 16:00:00        B 5.208333 days
17: 17 2022-10-08 17:00:00        B 6.250000 days
18: 18 2022-10-09 18:00:00        B 7.291667 days
19: 19 2022-10-10 19:00:00        B 8.333333 days
20: 20 2022-10-11 20:00:00        B 9.375000 days
```

The result should look like this:

```
    id           timestamp group_id        t_diff cluster_id
 1:  1 2022-10-02 01:00:00        A 0.000000 days          1
 2:  2 2022-10-03 02:00:00        A 1.041667 days          1
 3:  3 2022-10-04 03:00:00        A 2.083333 days          1
 4:  4 2022-10-05 04:00:00        A 3.125000 days          1
 5:  5 2022-10-06 05:00:00        A 4.166667 days          2
 6:  6 2022-10-07 06:00:00        A 5.208333 days          2
 7:  7 2022-10-08 07:00:00        A 6.250000 days          2
 8:  8 2022-10-09 08:00:00        A 7.291667 days          2
 9:  9 2022-10-10 09:00:00        A 8.333333 days          3
10: 10 2022-10-11 10:00:00        A 9.375000 days          3
11: 11 2022-10-02 11:00:00        B 0.000000 days          4
12: 12 2022-10-03 12:00:00        B 1.041667 days          4
13: 13 2022-10-04 13:00:00        B 2.083333 days          4
14: 14 2022-10-05 14:00:00        B 3.125000 days          4
15: 15 2022-10-06 15:00:00        B 4.166667 days          5
16: 16 2022-10-07 16:00:00        B 5.208333 days          5
17: 17 2022-10-08 17:00:00        B 6.250000 days          5
18: 18 2022-10-09 18:00:00        B 7.291667 days          5
19: 19 2022-10-10 19:00:00        B 8.333333 days          6
20: 20 2022-10-11 20:00:00        B 9.375000 days          6
```

I have tried an approch with lapply, but the code is ugly and very slow. I am looking for a data.table approach, but I don't know how to dynamically refer to the "first" observation.
By first observation I mean the first observation of the 4 day interval.

Answer (score -1):

You can use integer division.
Not that `as.numeric` run on a difftime object as an argument `units` that converts the difference to the desired time unit.

```
startDate <- as.POSIXct("2022-10-01")

dt1 <- data.table::data.table(
  id = 1:20,
  timestamp = startDate + lubridate::days(rep(1:10,2)) + lubridate::hours(1:20),
  group_id = rep(c("A","B"), each= 10)
)

# 
dt1[, GRP := as.numeric(timestamp - min(timestamp),
                        units = "days") %/% 4,
    by = group_id][]
#>     id           timestamp group_id GRP
#>  1:  1 2022-10-02 01:00:00        A   0
#>  2:  2 2022-10-03 02:00:00        A   0
#>  3:  3 2022-10-04 03:00:00        A   0
#>  4:  4 2022-10-05 04:00:00        A   0
#>  5:  5 2022-10-06 05:00:00        A   1
#>  6:  6 2022-10-07 06:00:00        A   1
#>  7:  7 2022-10-08 07:00:00        A   1
#>  8:  8 2022-10-09 08:00:00        A   1
#>  9:  9 2022-10-10 09:00:00        A   2
#> 10: 10 2022-10-11 10:00:00        A   2
#> 11: 11 2022-10-02 11:00:00        B   0
#> 12: 12 2022-10-03 12:00:00        B   0
#> 13: 13 2022-10-04 13:00:00        B   0
#> 14: 14 2022-10-05 14:00:00        B   0
#> 15: 15 2022-10-06 15:00:00        B   1
#> 16: 16 2022-10-07 16:00:00        B   1
#> 17: 17 2022-10-08 17:00:00        B   1
#> 18: 18 2022-10-09 18:00:00        B   1
#> 19: 19 2022-10-10 19:00:00        B   2
#> 20: 20 2022-10-11 20:00:00        B   2


# When you want a single ID index
# alternatovely, just you the combination of group_id and GRP in subsequent `by`s
dt1[, cluster_id := .GRP, by = .(group_id, GRP)][]
#>     id           timestamp group_id GRP cluster_id
#>  1:  1 2022-10-02 01:00:00        A   0          1
#>  2:  2 2022-10-03 02:00:00        A   0          1
#>  3:  3 2022-10-04 03:00:00        A   0          1
#>  4:  4 2022-10-05 04:00:00        A   0          1
#>  5:  5 2022-10-06 05:00:00        A   1          2
#>  6:  6 2022-10-07 06:00:00        A   1          2
#>  7:  7 2022-10-08 07:00:00        A   1          2
#>  8:  8 2022-10-09 08:00:00        A   1          2
#>  9:  9 2022-10-10 09:00:00        A   2          3
#> 10: 10 2022-10-11 10:00:00        A   2          3
#> 11: 11 2022-10-02 11:00:00        B   0          4
#> 12: 12 2022-10-03 12:00:00        B   0          4
#> 13: 13 2022-10-04 13:00:00        B   0          4
#> 14: 14 2022-10-05 14:00:00        B   0          4
#> 15: 15 2022-10-06 15:00:00        B   1          5
#> 16: 16 2022-10-07 16:00:00        B   1          5
#> 17: 17 2022-10-08 17:00:00        B   1          5
#> 18: 18 2022-10-09 18:00:00        B   1          5
#> 19: 19 2022-10-10 19:00:00        B   2          6
#> 20: 20 2022-10-11 20:00:00        B   2          6
```

Comment: Sorry for beeing unprecise. By "first observation" I didn't mean the first observation of the group, but rather the first observation of ech 4 day interval. Your answer works in the example dataset, but it will fail in some cases. Imagine an event of "2022-10-11 02:00:00". This event should fall in to cluster 2, but with your code it would fall into cluster 3.

Comment: then why is t_diff `0`  for the first observation of group B if you always want to refer to the first overall timestamp?

Comment: Because it is the first event of the first cluster in group B.

Comment: But `t_diff` is only zero for the first observation of each cluster, not for each 4 day intervall within each cluster. Would you please update your example dataset and desired solution. I do not see why my code fails to achieve what you want when it exactely produces what you want.

Comment: You are right, if you ignore the time of day. Imagine: Group A - Cluster 1 starts at 12:00. That means, that the cluster ends four days later at exactly 12:00. An event before 12:00 falls into Cluster 1. An event in the afternoon starts a new one, namely Cluster 2. If the afternoon event starts at 18:00 the following events will have to be assigned accordingly. For the interval definition of Cluster 2 I cannot refer to the Start timestamp of Cluster 1.  That your code worked for my dummy dataset is an unlucky coinsidence. I will change the dummy dataset.

Comment: Try the following data:(dt1 <- data.table(
  id = 1:20,
  timestamp = startDate+ lubridate::days(rep(1:10,2))+ lubridate::hours(rep(c(1,1,5,0,0,20,21,8,2,23), 2)),
  group_id = rep(c("A","B"), each= 10)
  ))

dt1[ , t_diff :=difftime(timestamp,data.table::first(timestamp), unit= "day"), by= group_id]